# How to aggregate data by certain conditions on SAS EG?

Tags: sql, sas

I have a question on aggregating the data, and the data structure looks like an example below: (`Table A`)

For example, the first row means 1/3 of the demand starting from 17JAN2016 will use for 1 day; and 1/3 will use for  2 days; the rest 1/3 will be used for 3 days.

```
ID   | Start_Date  | Length_of_Use | Percentage 
-------------------------------------------------
1    | 17JAN2017   |      1        |  0.333
2    | 17JAN2017   |      2        |  0.334
3    | 17JAN2017   |      3        |  0.333
4    | 18JAN2017   |      1        |  0.5
5    | 18JAN2017   |      4        |  0.5
6    | 19JAN2017   |      2        |  0.5
7    | 19JAN2017   |      3        |  0.5
8    | 20JAN2017   |      2        |  1
9    | 21JAN2017   |      1        |  1
```

And I do have Demand by Use date level as below: (`Table B`)

```
ID  | Use_Date      | Use_Demand 
----------------------------------- 
1   | 17JAN2017     |      3    
2   | 18JAN2017     |      4    
3   | 19JAN2017     |      4   
4   | 20JAN2017     |      4    
5   | 21JAN2017     |      5
```

If we have the above 2 tables as known information,
how could I merge `table A` and `table B` into a table that could have demand by Start Date & Length of Use level as below? (`Table C`)

ID is just a sequence number, no key information. 
First row is calculated by:

```
3*0.333 = 1
```

(Arrival Date 17JAN2016, Length of Use 1)

I would like to figure out demand by 'Start_Date' & 'Length_of_Use' level 
based on demand by 'Use_Date' level (`table B`) and Probability for each 'Starting_Date' and 'Length_of_Use' (`table A`).

As the example in `Table B`, 17JAN2017 has use_demand of 3, and according to the probability, 1 of them has length of use 1, whcih means the 'use_date' is 17JAN2017; 1 of them has length of use 2, whcih means the 'use_date' is 17JAN2017 and 18JAN2017; the rest 1 has  length of use 3, whcih means the 'use_date' is 17JAN2017, 18JAN2017 and 19JAN2017.

As in table B, 18JAN2017 has use_demand of 4, 2 of them come from 17JAN2017, hence, the rest 2 of them should come from 18JAN2017. Based on the probability table (table A), Starting_Date 18JAN2017 has 2 types of length of stay, both have probability 0.5; hence Start_Date '18JAN2017' with length of use 1 has demand 1, and '18JAN2017' with length of use 4 has demand 1; whcih makes 4th and 5th row of table C.

Thank you!

```
ID   | Start_Date     | Length_of_Use | Demand 
------------------------------------------------
1    | 17JAN2017      |      1        |  1
2    | 17JAN2017      |      2        |  1
3    | 17JAN2017      |      3        |  1
4    | 18JAN2017      |      1        |  1
5    | 18JAN2017      |      4        |  1
6    | 19JAN2017      |      2        |  1
7    | 19JAN2017      |      3        |  1
8    | 20JAN2017      |      2        |  1
9    | 21JAN2017      |      1        |  2
```

Comment: Why is last row's`Demand` equal to 2? Also, what is need of `Table B` ? Please explain more the calculated logic of `Demand`?

Comment: Hi Parfait, 21JAN2017 demand is calculated as 1 (Start: 18JAN2017 & Length of Use: 4) + 1(Start: 19JAN2017 & Length of Use: 3) + 1 (Start: 20JAN2017 & Length of Use: 2) + 2 (Start: 21JAN2017 & Length of Use: 1) = 5, which could corresponds to Table B. And I would like to obtain Table C, which is unknown and Table A & Table B is the information we have. Table A is the duration percentage information that Start demand could times the percentage and get actual use length. Thanks!